# Table values as parameters for SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1 :col1, col2, col3 and table2: col1, col2, col3
My goal is to get all records

```
where     
t2.col1 like t1.col1 and    
t2.col2 like t1.col2 and    
t2.col3 like t1.col3
```

........................................

One variant is the inner join method

```
select * from t2 inner join t1 on    
t2.col1 like t1.col1  and  
t2.col2 like t1.col2  and  
t2.col3 like t1.col3
```

........................................

Another variant is a stored procedure based on the 'where' clause:

```
select *  from t2     
where t2.col1 like parameter1  and      
t2.col2 like parameter2  and     
t2.col3 like parameter3
```

Then I call the procedure in VBA and  I use a for next loop to go through all values/parameters from an excel table1
........................................
Execution time for the join method is slower(~20, 30%) than vba+sp method, but unfortunately, for a big set of parameters, excel freeze.
........................................
Is possible to apply loop method and  go thru table1 values, as parameters for the stored procedure, inside sql server, in a sql script, no vba or c++ or perl etc. ?

I am a user with no access to db/tables design.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do the columns `col1`,`col2`, and `col3` have wildcards in them? If not, why are you using `LIKE`? Also, what exactly is your question here? What you ask at the bottom is very vague, but to answer your question *"Is possible to apply loop method and go thru table1 values, as parameters for the stored procedure, inside sql server, in a sql script, no vba or c++ or perl etc. ? "*: Yes, you can loop inside SQL Server; however, generally it's a bad idea, a data set approached will almost always be faster.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your tables?

Comment: *"values are between %"* What does that mean? That doesn't make any sense. Unless you're saying that Table1 has values in the columns like `'Green%Yellow%Red'`, however, that would mean your expression would be something like `'Green%Yellow%Red' LIKE 'Green'`, which would evaluate to false. If my guess is also true, however, you have a major problem with your design model.

Comment: col1: %value1%, %value2% etc. so, col1 like '%value1%'

Comment: Ok, Both table1 is on the left hand side of your expression, so `'%value1%' LIKE 'value1'` will evaluate to false. I think you need to post some sample data here, expected results, and expand on your question here. We have too little to go on right now. [How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: OK, now could you please update your question to have a specific question, and include sample data? it's also, however, worth noting that a query with a `WHERE` or `JOIN` which has a value with a preceding wildcard is non-SARGable (for example `WHERE [Column] LIKE '%yellow'`; thus any indexes won't be used and the performance of said query will therefore be severely hindered. Like i said before, I imagine the problem is your data model rather than your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your two queries in the question are not equivalent:

```
select * from t2 inner join t1 on    
t1.col1 like t2.col1  and  
t1.col2 like t2.col2  and  
t1.col3 like t2.col3
```

Here you have `t1 like t2`

```
select *  from t2     
where t2.col1 like parameter1  and      
t2.col2 like parameter2  and     
t2.col3 like parameter3
```

Here it is other way around `t2 like t1`.

End result would be different.

Based on the sample data it looks like it should be `t2 like t1`.

---

You can try to re-write the query using `CROSS APPLY` instead of `JOIN`, but it is unlikely to make any difference in performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    t1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
        FROM t2
        WHERE
            t2.col1 like t1.col1
            and t2.col2 like t1.col2
            and t2.col3 like t1.col3
    ) AS A
;
```

This query structure mimics your stored procedure approach where for each row from `t1` you select a set of rows from `t2`.

Comment: it works fine on a test tables. now i have to test on a real tables, t1 approx. 100, t2 approx millions

Comment: @user2284877, it would be interesting to know how it performs on the real tables compared to your VBA code.

Comment: join=cross over 47 minutes; (vba+where sp) =  1.03 minutes; table1 contains only one row: %keyword1% and %keyword2% and %keyword3%; all three methods returns (same)188 lines.

Comment: @user2284877, it should not take 47 minutes to read even 100M rows. The only thing that comes to mind is: what are the types of columns on the left and right of the `LIKE`? Are they the same in both tables?

Comment: t2 results from multiple joins, cols are concatenated and other colleagues run scripts on same table. but same conditions for select where in vba.